# Docker: Cannot start service nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on nginx service using docker-compose, I created the **docker-compose.yml** file :

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:1.11.8-alpine
        ports:
          - "8858:80"
        volumes:
          - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
          - ./html:/myapp
          - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
          - ./error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

This is the **site.conf** file

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location / {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /html {
       alias /myapp;
    }
}
```

This is the result of **docker-compose up**

> ERROR: for ef5152b88a7c_ef5152b88a7c_nginxdocker_nginx_1  Cannot start
>   service nginx: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting
>   container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused
>   \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\"/root/nginx-docker/nginx.conf\\"
>   to rootfs
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b463f0e0ca95db8cd570dfb68fcf206df31e86998e725465a7673ca192af8342\\"
>   at
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b463f0e0ca95db8cd570dfb68fcf206df31e86998e725465a7673ca192af8342/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\"
>   caused \\"not a directory\\"\""
>
> : Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?
>   Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

Comment: Are you sure `nginx.conf` exists in the host folder?

Comment: The error pretty clearly reffers to nginx.conf not existing in the folder the compose command was ran from

Comment: Thank you @Stefano for your response, after i check for the existance of the nginx.conf , it works fine , but now i'm facing new one  **nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (21: Is a directory)** and **[emerg] 1#1: no "events" section in configuration**

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Nginx.

If you use `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml`, always make sure that the files on the left side of the colon `:` exists! If you miss that, sometimes Docker Compose creates folders instead of files "on the left side" (= on your host) IIRC. Which leads to subsequent errors on the next run.

Comment: in this case, how to "reset" or remove the volume?

Comment: With `docker cp` you can copy folders and files from the running container to the empty volume.